# Django: how to add links to my admin site

Tags: django

I have this code in my admin-site,

```
@admin.register(StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Student_Users', 'School_Year', '<a href="#">link</a>',)
    ordering = ('Education_Levels',)
    list_filter = ('Student_Users',)
```

[Django-adminsite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkcJQ.png)
i just want to add an html_link here and filter what studentenrollmentrecord selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to be used as field:

```py
@admin.register(StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Student_Users', 'School_Year', 'link_display',)
    ordering = ('Education_Levels',)
    list_filter = ('Student_Users',)

    def link_display(self, obj):
        your_url = ''  # Define your URL here
        return '<a href="{}">link</a>'.format(your_url)

    link_display.allow_tags = True
    link_display.short_description = 'link'
```

The function receive the current object as first parameter (`obj`).
You need to set the `allow_tags` property to render your link.
You can optionally customize the description (displayed in the header) with `short_description`.